# HDMI monitor not receiving signal after waking up from suspend mode

Tags: 18.04, suspend, display, hdmi, signal

i have a problem that after I wake my ubuntu 18.04 laptop from the suspend mode, my HDMI monitor, which is set up a the primary monitor in the extended display set up, is not receiving the signal.
I have to unplug the HDMI cable and plug it back in every single time for it to get recognized.

As you can imagine this is highly annoying.

Is there a work around for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check if the monitor is with energy mode on? If it is so, try turn it off.

Comment: this worked, thank you .